# trouble to execute a SQL query through powershell because of double quotes inside the query

Tags: sql, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am playing around with Powershell and inserting Queries.

Now I have a Query which inserts some XML Syntax into my columns.

Since the Query syntax starts like this :

```
$SqlQuery = "Insert into..." and as well ends with double quotes I have trouble to insert something which already uses double quotes.
```

I need to insert this :
    div class="list tipGreen"

my error is : `Unexpected token 'list' in expression or statement...`

Can someone give me a hint, how to avoid this syntax problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use here-strings

```
$SqlQuery = @"
div class="list tipGreen"
"@
```

See help about_Quoting_Rules

Comment: Thank you, I needed to "escape" with ` before the "... now my code is : <div class=`"list tipGreen`">

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead.

```
$SqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO table SELECT ''' + text/variableWithSingleQuotesAroundIt + '''
```

Or

```
$SqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO table SELECT ' + text/variableWithNoQuotesAroundIt + '
```